# Understanding malloc and pointer incrementation with free

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, malloc, free

I am trying to understand the output of the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
    int *p = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    *p = 42;
    *(p+1) = 41;

    printf("%d -- %d\n", *p, p);
    printf("%d\n", p[0]);
    printf("%d -- %d\n", p[1], p+1);

    free(p);

    printf("%d --- %d\n", *p, p);
    printf("%d --- %d\n", p[1], p+1);
}
```

My understanding, step by step, is as follows:

```
int *p = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
```

*p* now points to a block of memory returned by *malloc*.

```
*p = 42;
```

Store the value *42* in the location returned by *malloc*.

```
*(p+1) = 41;
```

Store the value *41* in the location directly adjacent to that returned by *malloc*.

```
free(p);
```

Free the space pointed to by *p*, which was originally obtained by a call to *malloc*, i.e, the location of the int *42*.

The results:

```
42 -- 14327824
42
41 -- 14327828
0 --- 14327824
0 --- 14327828
```

My understanding is that the address *14327824* was returned by *malloc*. When the statement

```
*(p+1) = 41;
```

Is executed, the value *41* has been stored in a block **not returned** by *malloc*, i.e. *p+1*.

When free is called, I understand that it frees the space pointed to by *p*, i.e., the value *42*. Why then, is the value stored at *p+1* freed as well?

Also, if *malloc* returns a pointer *pt* to a block of uninitialized storage. Is the location *pt+1* beyond the bounds of the storage area set by *malloc*?

Comment: Touching memory outside what you allocate gives undefined results

Comment: This statement `*(p+1) = 41;` leads to *undefined behaviour*. The memory location `p+1` is not allocated by your program.

Comment: The reason that you are able to store a value in `p + 1` is probably because your `malloc` implementation allocated slightly more space than you asked for. It's possible that it only allocates memory in multiples of 16 bytes, for example.

Comment: The main thing you should do when you deal with Functions, is to learn them how are declared/defined and if there is a return remember it. So here (int *)malloc, (int *) is no needed because return of malloc is void* . The same thing for **main(){}** it should be **int main(void){}**

Comment: In practice it may be related to `malloc usable size`. C standard says that `malloc` must allocate enough space to hold objects of any size. On my GNU system `malloc_usable_size()` returns 12 even though only  `sizeof(int)` was requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is undefined behavior.

```
int *p = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
```

This allocates `sizeof(int)` bytes starting from the address returned by `malloc`.

When you do

```
*(p+1) = 41;
```

you are dereferencing to a memory location which has not been allocated on the heap. Its address is `p + sizeof(int)` which is an not managed address.

This yields undefined behavior and **every conclusion you can draw by observing the results is irrelevant**.

Comment: I disagree with the last sentence. You indeed can draw conclusions on what your compiler does with the undefined situation, but this behaviour may change at any time when something other changes: other compiler options or version etc. But it can be interesting to draw conclusions just to learn and extend your horizon. If you are talking about production programs, you are right, however. For them, it should be irrelevant because such constructs must be avoided in them.